# Connect to the internet through home network

Tags: vpn

I need to connect to my home network while away. I am guessing the solution to this is VPN but I have a few questions as I'm fairly new at this stuff. First of all is it possible to make it as simple as this: your home pc is the router and you are connecting your laptop to it but instead of using a cable you go through the internet. By this I mean same functionality as a home network and it also looks like this in your network and sharing center. Because as I understand it that's pretty much the idea of a VPN... Anyway I will try to make this question clearer if needed. Also I'm using Win 7 on my laptop and I am not sure whether I it will be better and even possible to set up a vpn server using some kind of Linux (not a pro at Linux, but I've used Fedora and Ubuntu a bit).
Thank you and I'll give more details if needed :)

Comment: you can set vpn server in windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you use your Gateway to connect to your home network and then you can config your laptop to accept Vpn connections that forwarded by your Gateway. if you just want to access your laptop easily you can use teamviewer software and connect to your laptop remotely but when you want to connect to your network you must config your gateways forwarding ports and rules!
let me know if you want more help.;)

Comment: Hmm OK that didn't make things clearer but I just have to try it I guess :) Also can you tell me some good program for setting up a VPN server under Linux?

Comment: @dukenukem see my new answer

Answer (score 0):

i am assuming you are using a Redhat or Redhat-like distribution. Some of these packages can be grabbed via yum. However, I'm going to have you install them via RPM as you cannot get all of them via yum. If you are not, you will need to get the proper packages. For Debian you can use aptget or search for the .deb. For SuSe you can use Yast or find the distro specific RPMs.

### Set up a Linux VPN server by following these 10 steps

1) Install the DKMS package

```
rpm --install dkms-1.12-2.noarch.rpm
```

http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/poptop/dkms-1.12-2.noarch.rpm

This is dynamic kernel module support. You need this to simplify setup and configuration at the kernel level. This will make almost everything transparent to the user during setup.

2) Install the ppp kernel module

```
rpm --install kernel_ppp_mppe-0.0.4-2dkms.noarch.rpm
```

http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/poptop/kernel_ppp_mppe-0.0.4-2dkms.noarch.rpm

Point to Point Protocol to setup your "modem" or whatever your connection consists of. This is the portion for your kernel.

3) Make sure ppp is working

```
modprobe ppp-compress-18 && echo arashams has saved me from a life of Windows;)
```

Ok, so that is a bit of fun, but what does that command mean? Well, if on success of the modprobe command, I execute the echo command. Modprobe adds the module to the Linux kernel, while echo simply writes what ever you say back to the terminal.

4) Upgrade ppp

```
rpm --upgrade ppp-2.4.3-0.cvs_20040527.4.fc2.i386.rpm
```

http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/poptop/ppp-2.4.3-0.cvs_20040527.4.fc2.i386.rpm

This is the ppp for the user. The kernel module for ppp has been installed and this is for the user

5) Get the PPTP client

```
rpm --install pptp-linux-1.5.0-1.i386.rpm
```

http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/pptpclient/pptp-linux-1.5.0-1.i386.rpm

This is the "VPN Client," so to speak. This is the GUI client in which you can setup VPN connections and various options.

6) Get phppcntl

```
rpm --install Getphp-pcntl php-pcntl-4.3.8-1.i386.rpm
```

http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/pptpclient/php-pcntl-4.3.8-1.i386.rpm

This is to help the GUI work.

7) Get the phpgtkmodule

```
rpm --install php-gtk-pcntl-1.0.0-2.i386.rpm
```

http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/pptpclient/php-gtk-pcntl-1.0.0-2.i386.rpm

This file also helps make the GUI work.
8) Get pptpconfig installed

```
rpm --install pptpconfig-20040722-0.noarch.rpm
```

http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/pptpclient/pptpconfig-20040722-0.noarch.rpm

This command installs the Point to Point Tunneling Protocol. This is so the VPN can actually create the tunnel from A to B. VPNs can use two protocols, L2TP and PPTP. L2TP is Layer 2 Tunneling Protocol and does just what it says. It works at Layer 2 in the OSI model, the Data Link Layer.
9) Now at the command line type

```
pptpconfig
```

This command will popup a spiffy GUI for you to use.

10) Configure your connection

In the Server Tab we need to configure some basics:

```
Name: The name of the connection. You can call it anything you want
Server: The server you are connecting to, either the IP or name of the server. eg: 64.233.187.99 or google.com
Domain: A domain, if any, that the VPN is connecting to
Username: Your login username for the VPN or the intranet
Password: The login password for the VPN or the intranet
```

In the Routing Tab we need to make sure it is setup properly. Typically we need to send All to Tunnel.However, this can and will vary from VPN to VPN. Check with you local administrator on what radio button you need to choose.

The DNS Tab is usually quite simple; it will be either automatic, or we will have to enter some basic DNS information and any optionswe may need to include.

The Encryption Tab is a sticky point. We have a number of choices:

```
Require Microsoft PointtoPoint Encryption
Refuse 40bit Encryption
Refuse 128bit Encryption
Refuse Stateless Encryption
Refuse to Authenticate with EAP
```

You need to talk to your administrator and understand what your VPN requires. A typical setup will check box Require Microsoft PointtoPoint Encryption (for MS VPNS), Refuse 40bit Encryption, and Refuse Stateless Encryption. However, talk to your administrator to be sure.

The Miscellaneous Tab is our final tab. We shouldn't have anything to do here. The default setup should work just fine in many cases.

We now click the Addbutton and highlight our new connection and choose Start. We have now created a VPN connection to a remote host! Congratulations for using Linux and sticking with a slightly frustrating task.

reference:James M. Garvin